# Sets with conditions in python

Tags: python, bash

Normally, in bash, I can do:

```
labels=(label1 label2)
value=([label1]="value1" [label2]="value2")
```

Bash script is something like below:

```
for label in $labels:
   command $value
```

Currently, what I'm doing with python in order to achieve similar result is:

```
labels = ("label1", "label2")
value = ("value1", "value2")

for label in labels:
    command value[labels.index(label)]
```

However, I think it's quite an unclean way to do this. Is there any better way?

Comment: @That1Guy short snippets like this are not acceptable on CR.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dictionaries for this - [[Documentation]](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) .

They are `key:value` pairs, and you can get the value using the key.

Example -

```
>>> dct = {'label1':'value1' , 'label2':'value2'}
>>>
>>>
>>> for labels in dct:
...     print('label - ' + labels)
...     print('value - ' + dct[labels])
...
label - label1
value - value1
label - label2
value - value2
```

A tutorial to help you start on Dictionaries - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a dictionary. The dictionary has pairs of keys and values that you can iterate through.

```
commands = {
    "label1": "value1",
    "label2": "value2"
}

for label, value in commands.iteritems():
    print(label)
    command(value)
```